# li:nth-child(x):hover works partially

Tags: html, css

I successfully managed to make my li element hover using nth-child(). In each of these section works fine individually. However, when they are put in a row there are sections where the hover does not work. I apologize if my question if as vague as my understanding of the problem. Please here is the concerning my code:

When I only keep one section, it's working fine whereas it wasn't compatible with the others.

the body of my question.html file

```
<section class="wrapper after-nav">
            <ul class="stage">
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#artiste" class="btn-grad">Artiste</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#startup" class="btn-grad">Start Ups</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#sportif" class="btn-grad">Sportif</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#independant" class="btn-grad">Indépendant</a></li>
            </ul>

    </section>
    <a name="artiste"/>
    <section class="wrapper-artiste">
    <ul class="stage">
                <li class="languette-out"><a href="#artiste" class="btn-grad">Artiste</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#startup" class="btn-grad">Start Ups</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#sportif" class="btn-grad">Sportif</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#independant" class="btn-grad">Indépendant</a></li>
            </ul>
    </section>
    <a name="startup"/>
    <section class="wrapper-startup" style="background-color: green;">
        <ul class="stage">
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#artiste" class="btn-grad">Artiste</a></li>
                <li class="languette-out"><a href="#startup" class="btn-grad">Start Ups</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#sportif" class="btn-grad">Sportif</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#independant" class="btn-grad">Indépendant</a></li>
            </ul>

    </section>
    <a name="sportif"/>
    <section class="wrapper-sportif" style="background-color: blue;">
        <ul class="stage">
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#artiste" class="btn-grad">Artiste</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#startup" class="btn-grad">Start Ups</a></li>
                <li class="languette-out"><a href="#sportif" class="btn-grad">Sportif</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#independant" class="btn-grad">Indépendant</a></li>
            </ul>

    </section>
    <a name="independant"/>
    <section class="wrapper-independant" style="background-color: purple;">
         <ul class="stage">
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#artiste" class="btn-grad">Artiste</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#startup" class="btn-grad">Start Ups</a></li>
                <li class="languette-in"><a href="#sportif" class="btn-grad">Sportif</a></li>
                <li class="languette-out"><a href="#independant" class="btn-grad">Indépendant</a></li>
        </ul>

    </section>
```

question.css

```
.btn-grad {
  padding: 10% 0;
  color: black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ECE9E6 0%, #FFFFFF 51%, #ECE9E6 100%)
}
.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper-artiste{
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper-startup{
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper-sportif{
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;

  top: 300%;
}
.wrapper-independant{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;

  top: 400%;

}

.stage{
  width: 15%;
  padding: 0;
}


ul.stage li.languette-in {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}

ul.stage li.languette-out {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}


ul.stage li:nth-child(1):hover{
  left: 0;
}
ul.stage li:nth-child(2):hover{
  left: 0;
}
ul.stage li:nth-child(3):hover{
  left: 0;
}
ul.stage li:nth-child(4):hover{
  left: 0;
}
ul.stage li a{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left:0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  Plase reduce your code to just the essential issue.

Comment: I have a couple ideas but I don't know what is actually wrong? My first thought is you don't need an nth-of-type rule at all. Try remove the nth-of-type(x). As when you hover the css can already identify which li is being hovered.

Comment: The problem is caused by the errors in your HTML. There are no end tags on the <a> elements between the sections, so part of each section is put inside the preceding <a>, up until the first </a> in the section. This throws the count of the <li> elements off. Run your source through a validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the `a` tags with `name` attribute or close them properly with a closing tag. `a` tag is not empty element like `img` or `br` element, you need to close it like this `<a href="your_link_goes_here"></a>`. Moreover `name` is not an appropriate attribute for `a` element. [Check this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) to find out which attribute goes with which element.

Instead of using `a` tag for navigation, you should use `id` attribute to the respective `section`. See the example below.

Moreover you don't need the ":nth-child" rule at all. instead of `ul.stage li:nth-child(1):hover` you can and should use just `ul.stage li:hover`.

Hope that helps. Happy coding :)

```css
html{
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn-grad {
  text-decoration: none;
  border:none;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
  padding: 10% 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin:4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ECE9E6 0%, #FFFFFF 51%, #ECE9E6 100%)}
.btn-grad:hover 
{ 
  background-position: 
  right center; 
}
.wrapper{
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1CD8D2;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #93EDC7, #1CD8D2);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #93EDC7, #1CD8D2); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.wrapper-artiste{
  overflow: auto;
  background: #3D7EAA;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FFE47A, #3D7EAA);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFE47A, #3D7EAA); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*top: -100px;*/
}
.wrapper-startup{
  overflow: auto;
  background: #9CECFB;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0052D4, #65C7F7, #9CECFB);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0052D4, #65C7F7, #9CECFB); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200%;
  width: 100%;

  /*top: -200px;*/
}
.wrapper-sportif{
  overflow: auto;
  background: #5f2c82;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #49a09d, #5f2c82);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #49a09d, #5f2c82); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;

  top: 300%;
  /*top: -300px;*/
}
.wrapper-independant{
  overflow: auto;
  background: #4b6cb7;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #182848, #4b6cb7);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #182848, #4b6cb7); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;

  top: 400%;

  /*top: -400px;*/
}

.next-svg{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
  animation-name: next;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.next-svg:hover{
  animation-name: next;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes next{ 
  0% { top: 0px; }
  10% { top: 2px; }
  20% { top: 4px; }
  30% {top: 6px;}
  40% { top: 8px; }
  50% { top: 10px; }
  60% { top: 8px; }
  70% { top: 6px; }
  80% { top: 4px; }
  90% { top: 2px; }
  100% {top: 0px;}
}
.next-svg polyline{
  fill:none;
  stroke:white;
  stroke-width:5
}

.svg-container{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}
.svg-container-center-bottom{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 45%;

}
.center-page{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
.stage{
  width: 15%;
  padding: 0;
}


ul.stage li.languette-in {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}

ul.stage li.languette-out {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

ul.stage li:hover{
  left: 0;
}
ul.stage li a{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="wrapper after-nav">
        <ul class="stage">
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#artiste" class="btn-grad">Artiste</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#startup" class="btn-grad">Start Ups</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#sportif" class="btn-grad">Sportif</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#independant" class="btn-grad">Indépendant</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="svg-container-center-bottom">
            <a href="#artiste"><svg class="next-svg" height="50" width="100">
                    <polyline points="0,0 50,20 100,0" />
                    <polyline points="0,20 50,40 100,20" />
                    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
                </svg>
            </a>
        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="wrapper-artiste" id="artiste">
        <ul class="stage">
            <li class="languette-out"><a href="#artiste" class="btn-grad">Artiste</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#startup" class="btn-grad">Start Ups</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#sportif" class="btn-grad">Sportif</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#independant" class="btn-grad">Indépendant</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="svg-container-center-bottom">
            <a href="#startup"><svg class="next-svg" height="50" width="100">
                    <polyline points="0,0 50,20 100,0" />
                    <polyline points="0,20 50,40 100,20" />
                    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
                </svg>
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="wrapper-startup" style="background-color: green;" id="startup">
        <ul class="stage">
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#artiste" class="btn-grad">Artiste</a></li>
            <li class="languette-out"><a href="#startup" class="btn-grad">Start Ups</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#sportif" class="btn-grad">Sportif</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#independant" class="btn-grad">Indépendant</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="svg-container-center-bottom">
            <a href="#sportif"><svg class="next-svg" height="50" width="100">
                    <polyline points="0,0 50,20 100,0" />
                    <polyline points="0,20 50,40 100,20" />
                    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
                </svg>
            </a>
        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="wrapper-sportif" style="background-color: blue;" id="sportif">
        <ul class="stage">
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#artiste" class="btn-grad">Artiste</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#startup" class="btn-grad">Start Ups</a></li>
            <li class="languette-out"><a href="#sportif" class="btn-grad">Sportif</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#independant" class="btn-grad">Indépendant</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="svg-container-center-bottom">
            <a href="#independant"><svg class="next-svg" height="50" width="100">
                    <polyline points="0,0 50,20 100,0" />
                    <polyline points="0,20 50,40 100,20" />
                    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
                </svg>
            </a>
        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="wrapper-independant" style="background-color: purple;" id="independant">
        <ul class="stage">
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#artiste" class="btn-grad">Artiste</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#startup" class="btn-grad">Start Ups</a></li>
            <li class="languette-in"><a href="#sportif" class="btn-grad">Sportif</a></li>
            <li class="languette-out"><a href="#independant" class="btn-grad">Indépendant</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="svg-container-center-bottom">
            <a href="#mission"><svg class="next-svg" height="50" width="100">
                    <polyline points="0,0 50,20 100,0" />
                    <polyline points="0,20 50,40 100,20" />
                    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
                </svg>
            </a>
        </div>

    </section>

</body>

</html>
```